# Do I need to define a Schema when using Mongoose to obtain data from CSV file imported to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, express, mongoose

I used mongoimport to add a csv file into MongoDB. In my node.js application I planned to create a Mongoose model to access that data however I'm confused as to whether I need to create a Schema in order to access the data within MongoDB. My CSV file already contains header lines which I incorporated during the mongoimport. If I were to create a new Schema, do I use those headers and simply map the correct data type to them?

For example, the csv headers were "User_ID", "Name", "Hometown", "Age", and "Birthday".

Would I need to create a schema like this:

```
const dataSchema = new Schema({

User_ID: {
type: ObjectID,
unique: true
},
Name: String,
Hometown: String,
Age: Number,
Birthday: Date

});

const dataModel = mongoose.model('Data', dataSchema);

module.exports = dataModel;
```

Comment: yes, if you want to use that data in your application

Comment: Thanks @georoot. I was successful in fetching that data and displaying it in my Views file however I ran into a slight issue. One of the header lines had a space (Example: Work Occupation) so I presented it in the data Schema as Work_Occupation.  The problem is, that unlike the single word header lines (Example: Name, Hometown, etc) that key value pair is not listed in quotations, ie. 'Work Occupation'. How would I access that variable if I'm looping through each object (no issue looping through the others, example: data.Name, data.Hometown)?

Comment: Hi i didn't exactly get what you are trying to say, attach mongoose schema, database model schema and the part of code that you are having issues with in the question. BTW just a tip mongoose schema are just json nothing more :)